# Data on fragment is not loaded when i implement toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I'm working on navigation drawer with expandable listview and the issue is with toolbar. When i implement toolbar for the parent appcompactActivity than only the toolbar is being loaded without any fragment data. The code is working fine when there is no toolbar. I think you will understand my problem. 
Thanks in advance.

**Update**
I'm not getting how to update my code so that i'm sharing the link which i used as a reference to develop my app base. 
Source : [Github](https://github.com/msahakyan/expandable-navigation-drawer)

The change i made is in styles, the given project uses action bar and i've implemented material design so used a toolbar in main activity.

Please do consider as i was new to stackoverflow

Comment: Without fragments of your code it will be extremely difficult to solve your problem ?

Comment: Provide `Java` code of adapter and fragment

Comment: Thanks @Myway  for responding. Sorry, i'm not able to share my code but i updated the question with a link i used as reference

Comment: Thanks @xAqweRx for responding i've updated my question please check it out